# why can't this function hide both questionOne and questionTwo?

Tags: javascript

I have created this function that would search for div by class and replace string to dashes when a button is clicked

```
// Question ONE

var answer = new Array();
answer[0] = "どうぞ";
answer[1] = " 宜しく";

document.querySelector(".questionOne").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + answer[1] + '<img " class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';

function showit2(){
    document.querySelector(".questionOne").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + answer[1] + '<img " class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';
}

function showit(){
    document.querySelector(".questionOne").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + " _ _ _ " + '<img  onclick="showit2()" class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';
}

function hideit(){
  document.querySelector(".questionOne").innerHTML= "L1: _ _ _  . _ _ _ " + '<img  onclick="showit()" class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">' ;

    document.querySelector(".questionTwo").innerHTML= "L1: _ _ _  . _ _ _ " + '<img  onclick="showit()" class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">' ;

}




// Question Two


answer = new Array();
answer [0] = "あなた";
answer [1] = "の";
answer [2] = "出身";
answer [3] = "は";
answer [4] = "どこ";
answer [5] = "ですか？"

document.querySelector(".questionTwo").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + answer[1] + " . " + answer [2] + " . " + answer [3] + " . " + answer [4] + " . " + answer [5] + '<img " class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';

function showit2(){
    document.querySelector(".questionTwo").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + answer[1] + '<img " class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';
}

function showit(){
    document.querySelector(".questionTwo").innerHTML= "L1: " + answer[0] + " . " + " _ _ _ " + '<img  onclick="showit2()" class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">';
}

function hideit(){
  document.querySelector(".questionTwo").innerHTML= "L1: _ _ _  . _ . _ _ . _ . _ _ . _ _ _ " + '<img  onclick="showit()" class="getAnswer"  src="assets/images/getAnswer.png">' ;
}
```

when I run this on the first one it works well , how ever as I added the 2nd part for question two, now when I click the hide button, it applies the hide only on question 2 and not question one anymore! WHY ?

Comment: The code is a bit confusing. You have multiple definitions of your functions.

Comment: How can I fix plz

Comment: @lurker is right - you have defined all of your functions twice. Give all your functions unique names.

Comment: got it fixed / thanx :)

Comment: I'm glad you are pleased, but the question's functions are still wrong. There are still duplicates.

Comment: That’s what I was was gonna ask next I’m gonna post another question with all my code to this app and Ill link it here so when u see it if u can go to the new post I’ll make and tell me what u think I’d really appreciate it man

Comment: It's probably best just to delete this question when you create your new one. The duplicate functions make it of little value once you've corrected that issue.